# Postgresql select based on another select with order, limit and agregate

Tags: postgresql

I have a tables like:

books:

```
id | title      | rating_avr | visible
1  | 'Overlord' | 5          | true
2  | 'Avengers' | 10         | false
```

tags_books:

```
tag_id | book_id | likes
1      | 1       | 5
2      | 1       | 25
1      | 2       | 11
```

tags:

```
id | name
1  | 'Adventure'
2  | 'Drama'
```

Now i need to load books that have tag 'Drama' with LIMIT, ORDER and agregate tags for each book.

I managed to achive this using query:

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, b.rating_avr, json_agg(json_build_object('id', tb2.tag_id)) as tags
FROM books b
LEFT JOIN tags_books tb ON tb.book_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN tags_books tb2 ON tb2.book_id = b.id
WHERE tb.tag_id = 1 AND b.visible=true 
GROUP BY b.id ORDER BY b.rating_avr DESC LIMIT 5
```

What i'm curious about:

1) Is it ok to join same table 2 times? First is for where clause and second to agregate tags.

2) How can i order agregated tags based on likes?

3) Is it a right approach, or maybe there is better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange that in your query, you don't use the table `tags`, although you want to fetch books with tag `'Drama'` which is a column in the table `tags`.
What I would do is first get the ids of all the books with tag `'Drama'` with a query like this:

```
SELECT b.id FROM books b
INNER JOIN tags_books tb ON tb.book_id = b.id
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id = tb.tag_id
WHERE t.name = 'Drama' AND b.visible=true
```

and then use it to get the result:

```
SELECT 
  b.id, b.title, b.rating_avr, 
  json_agg(json_build_object('id', tb.tag_id) order by tb.likes desc) as tags
FROM books b INNER JOIN tags_books tb
ON tb.book_id = b.id
WHERE b.id IN (
  SELECT b.id FROM books b
  INNER JOIN tags_books tb ON tb.book_id = b.id
  INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id = tb.tag_id
  WHERE t.name = 'Drama' AND b.visible=true
)
GROUP BY b.id, b.title, b.rating_avr
ORDER BY b.rating_avr DESC LIMIT 5
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=cdb8ef35a581db0a2f4d13f063b0f674).
Results:

```
> id | title    | rating_avr | tags                    
> -: | :------- | ---------: | :-----------------------
>  1 | Overlord |          5 | [{"id" : 2}, {"id" : 1}]
```

Comment: Ok, but what a difference with my approach and how to order agregated tags using likes?

Comment: The difference with your approach is that you use the id of the tag that you search for instead of the name. Do you know the id of what you search? Also I use inner joins instead of left since you don't need all the rows of a table when you join it to the others but only these rows that satisfy a condition. The order is the same as in your question: `rating_avr`

Comment: Yes i know tag_id. Problem is that i need to sort books by rating and agregated tags by likes (question 2), is that possible?

Comment: Edited again, I guess you want them sorted descending.